# Reject TXs based on fee in comparison to TX size?

Tags: transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, mempool

Is it possible to configure a node to reject junk transactions like this
https://tradeblock.com/bitcoin/tx/6d67480fde2dd484b0ee389a6488db212ea7d0dbd2a11358efcc0b39077407ca

199 inputs, 35kb tx with a tiny 0.0003 fee.

There's `minrelaytxfee`, but I'm looking for something that is based on both fee and tx size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

minrelayfee is already in BTC/kB, so that's exactly what you need.

> 35kb tx with a tiny 0.0003 fee.

Didn't do the math, but I think even the default minrelayfee should block those.

Comment: Ah okay, didn't know that, thanks. It's showing in my mempool, and my mempool is getting awfully large lately, over 30,000 txs. Thought maybe adding some like this could help...

Comment: Are you running a recent version? The relayfee stuff had been changed a bit over the past few versions. What is your current minrelayfee setting?

Comment: [relayfee] => 5.0E-5  (0.00005)